# Traceback message pop up and receiving type error on read.excel()

Tags: python

My project is to carry out analysis using python. I have some data on excel but I only need to use some data not all the data (ie. specific date like only from january to february).
My question is

1. How do I select only desired data (like specific date) and insert into the python code?
2. I got this error when I try to run the file (PMEB_Para.py), May I know what does the error means?
   This is the error i received

```
     C:\Users\user\Desktop\CIV4210\Research\Package for FYP\data and code>python PMEB_Main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "PMEB_Main.py", line 483, in <module>
    Tb, Station, Rough, Veg, Sp = readdata(Para.period)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\CIV4210\Research\Package for FYP\data and code\PMEB_Para.py", line 397, in readdata
    rough = pd.read_excel('roughness.xlsx', parse_dates=['Dt'], dtype=Dtype, dayfirst=True)
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 296, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: read_excel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'dayfirst'
```

The code at line 390-397 from PMEB_Para.py file

```
def readdata(period):
station = readstation(period)
tb = pd.read_csv('TB.csv', dtype=Dtype, parse_dates=['Dt'], dayfirst=True)
tb = tb.loc[(tb['Dt'] > period[0]) & (tb['Dt'] < period[1])]
tb['Date'] = [x.date() for x in tb['Dt']]
tb['Time'] = [x.time() for x in tb['Dt']]
tb = tb.sort_values(['Date', 'Quad', 'BI', 'Pol'])
rough = pd.read_excel('roughness.xlsx', parse_dates=['Dt'], dtype=Dtype, dayfirst=True)
```

Thank you for your time in advance!